# Rails: set a default value to be same as record's ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My table has a column "order" that I want initially set to equal the record's ID.

Can I do this in the migration, or do I need to set it in the create action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have data, you can't do this in a create callback action because those items have already been created.  However, a create callback would help you for new objects you will create:

```
after_create :set_order_attribute

def set_order_attribute
  self.update_columns(order: id) if order.nil?
end
```

You can technically update existing data in a migration as a SQL statement, but I wouldn't recommend using commands involving the ActiveRecord model as the migration may break sometime down the line as the model changes.  To do this in a migration you would have an execute command in the :up method (not sure what behavior you would want for :down) like so:

```
def up
  table_name = "foo"
  execute "UPDATE #{table_name} SET order = id;"
end
```

Alternatively you could create a separate rake task to do the update; this would keep your migrations cleaner and give you better control over when you will run the update task.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this didn't work for me until I used `after_create`.

Comment: @Fomentia That would be because `id` is not set until the object is created in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the value passed to :default in the migration cannot be a variable. I would try a callback like this:

```
    before_save :initialize_order

    def initialize_order
      self.order = self.id
    end
```

Comment: Instead of before_save before_create is recommended in this scenario.